# Virtual machine with status aborted : VERIF_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows virtual machine that worked fine until I went to Setting and shared a directory then the machine changes its status to aborted and when I try to launch it with this status "Aborted" it crashes directly. Honestly I don' t know what's happening especially I've done  this manipulation many times and everything went good!

1-I removed the vdi disk and insert it again, then launch it-> same issue.
2-I've reboot my laptop and re-do manipulations 1- -> not working either

And I really need it in order to finish my exam, I had all my files inside and all the backup I had is not updated at all unfortunalety...

Here are the logs :

```
00:00:09.417355 VirtualBox VM 7.0.2 r154219 win.amd64 (Oct 19 2022 21:29:26) release log
00:00:09.417358 Log opened 2022-11-30T23:06:54.788998300Z
00:00:09.417358 Build Type: release
00:00:09.417386 OS Product: Windows 10
00:00:09.417387 OS Release: 10.0.19045
00:00:09.417433 OS Service Pack: 
00:00:09.679509 DMI Product Name: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X580GD_K2N0CV00S455063
00:00:09.687623 DMI Product Version: 1.0       
00:00:09.687630 Firmware type: UEFI
00:00:09.688148 Secure Boot: VERR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD
00:00:09.688163 Host RAM: 16235MB (15.8GB) total, 8874MB (8.6GB) available
00:00:09.688166 Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBoxVM.exe
00:00:09.688166 Process ID: 12068
00:00:09.688166 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:09.689120 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:09.689142   Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack (Version: 6.1.38 r153438; VRDE Module: VBoxVRDP; Crypto Module:  unusable because of 'VBoxExtPackVMRegister returned VERR_VERSION_MISMATCH, pReg=0000000000000000 ErrInfo='Helper version mismatch - expected 0x30000 got 0x50000'')
00:00:09.690229 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:09.698448 Qt version: 5.15.2
00:00:09.703801 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:09.710228 Power up failed (vrc=VINF_SUCCESS, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:09.710547 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished!
00:00:09.781529 GUI: UIMachineViewScale::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 3840x1875
00:00:09.781588 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={4680b2de-8690-11e9-b83d-5719e53cf1de} aComponent={DisplayWrap} aText={The console is not powered up (Display::setVideoModeHint)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:09.781856 GUI: Aborting startup due to power up progress issue detected...
00:00:09.790551 GUI: UICommon: Handling aboutToQuit request..
00:00:10.354268 GUI: UICommon: aboutToQuit request handled!
```

here is the picture :

[image: Aborted launch]

Comment: The first obvious question I have is, do all snapshots that were created for the VM, currently exist on the disk?  The error seems to suggest the current snapshot, which would be required to boot the VM, does not exist on the disk.

Comment: @Ramhound In my directory BE Malware Win 10\Snapshots I have a file .nvram (is that answering your question??)

Comment: If you don't have the necessary snapshot file `{d1f6c592-6b4b-45ba-a23f-be0148121406}.vdi` in that folder then your VM does not have the necessary files to boot.  The fact the VM suddenly forcefully shutdown is likely the reason the file no longer exists.  Unless you have a backup, there is no solution to your problem, you don't have the necessary files to boot your VM.

Comment: Do you have a backup?  I had a Windows 10 VMware VM go south on me. Windows Defender quarantined it. I do not know why. I used a backup VM from my other computer.

Comment: VirtualBox uses all snapshots that might have been created in order to boot the primary virtual HDD within the VM.  Without the snapshot specificed in the error the system cannot boot.